# AQTime: "Force Garbage Collection" button grayed out

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, mixed, aqtime

I googled around a bit, but couldn't find a reason.
My app is mixed (C#, VB.NET, C++/CLI and native C++). AQTime claims to be able to profile this kind of application, that's why I chose it.

It does profile OK, but it would be nice to be able to force Garbage Collection to rule out objects which are garbage but haven't been collected yet from the suspicious set.

I'm running the Allocation Profiler over an area of my code (some dlls), with these settings:

- Check system memory Allocations: checked (all other unchecked)
- Collect Stack information: None
- Thread Model: CLR threads (I figured this would be necessary since the GC handles managed threads, doesn't it?)

AQTime version is 6.50.498, running on Windows XP Professional SP3

Is it possible to use the "Force Garbage Collection" feature in this scenario? If so, how do I configure AQTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known problem with calling Garbage Collection from AQtime when profiling .NET Framework 4 applications - this function does not work for applications running under this version of .NET Framework. For earlier .NET Framework versions, this should work just fine.

There is no solution to the problem so far, but the investigation is going to be continued soon.

--

Alex

Comment: ( Damn! Almost got the Tumbleweed badge :P ) That's weird... While I was waiting for an answer, I downloaded a trial of AQTime 7 Pro, which claims to be integrated into Visual Studio 2010. So I'd expect full support for .NET 4.0... But not only does Visual Studio 2010 Integration crash, the standalone AQTime 7 works but the garbage collection button is still grayed out... Now I use AQTime to identify the leaking class(es), and a custom object allocation logger to pinpoint leaks and call GC.Collect() before dumping

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed in [AQtime 8](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/application-performance-profiling/features/new-aqtime-pro-features/aqtime-8-0).